# Multiple if statements in makefile conditionals

Tags: makefile

The make documentation says the syntax of a **complex conditional** is as follows:

```
conditional-directive-one
text-if-one-is-true
else conditional-directive-two
text-if-two-is-true
else
text-if-one-and-two-are-false
endif
```

But I don't understand how to use this syntax to rewrite the following piece of code:

```
ifeq ($(option), 1)
CC=gcc
@echo use gcc
else ifeq($(option), 2)
CC=clang
@echo use clang
else
CC=mipsel-linux-gcc
@echo use mipsel-linux-gcc
endif

#first target
foo: ;
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want to "rewrite" that code.  Is there a problem with it?  If so what is the problem?  I'll point out two things: first, you need a space after the `ifeq` in `else ifeq($(option), 2)`.  Second, that syntax was added to GNU make in version 3.81 so if you have an older version it's not available.

Comment: I omit the space after the `ifeq` and my `text-if-one-is-true`,`text-two-is-true`,`text-if-one-and-two-are-false` blocks contain recipes before the first target(They are not shown here). These two things make my Makefile don't work.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand.  You need to _add_ a space after the `ifeq`, not omit one.  When asking questions please show a minimal example of the _actual_ problem, not a different example that may not show the problem.  Also please cut and paste the exact error message you see.  In your comment you  mention "contain recipes before the first target" which is a completely different kind of error, that cannot happen only with the example makefile you show above.

Comment: I mean that I left out a space after the `ifeq` which make the make file don't work. And I don't know that I can't write recipes before the first target so I erase them from the previous version code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO, `ifeq` statements take too much space, harder to type and read. A better alternative:

```
CC.1 := gcc
CC.2 := clang
CC := $(or ${CC.${option}},mipsel-linux-gcc)
$(info "Using ${CC}")
```

Answer (score 9):

Using your makefile:

```
ifeq ($(option), 1)
    CC=gcc
    @echo use gcc
else ifeq($(option), 2)
    CC=clang
    @echo use clang
else
    CC=mipsel-linux-gcc
    @echo use mipsel-linux-gcc
endif

#first target
foo:
    echo CC $(CC)
```

I get the following error:

```
$ make
Makefile:4: Extraneous text after `else' directive
Makefile:6: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

Editing the makefile as per suggestion from @MadScientist (i.e. a space after the `ifeq`):

```
ifeq ($(option), 1)
    CC=gcc
    @echo use gcc
else ifeq ($(option), 2)
    CC=clang
    @echo use clang
else
    CC=mipsel-linux-gcc
    @echo use mipsel-linux-gcc
endif

#first target
foo:
    echo CC $(CC)
```

I get:

```
$ make
Makefile:9: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

This is saying you can't use a command unless it's part of a rule. If you want to log something like that, try it like this:

```
ifeq ($(option), 1)
    CC=gcc
else ifeq ($(option), 2)
    CC=clang
else
    CC=mipsel-linux-gcc
endif

$(info CC is $(CC))

#first target
foo:
    @echo foo
```

From this, I get:

```
$ make
CC is mipsel-linux-gcc
foo
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html#index-error for more info on `$(info ...)` - you can put it inside the conditionals if you want, but why would you? :->

Comment: Thanks, but Maxim's answer is so simple and elegant.